# How to add ArrayList items with same type to another?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Is there any easier way to add items from one List to another? I've tried the code below and result is ok. But I wonder is it any simpler way to do this? Thank you.

```
 ArrayList<Channel_Show_Model> items=getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(FORWARDED_ITEMS_FROM_MAIN);

   for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
       String t=items.get(i).getTitle();
       String t2=items.get(i).getMessage();
       boolean b=items.get(i).getStatus();
       data.add(new Channel_Show_Model(t,t2,b));
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use this

```
data.addAll(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java-8 you can use `Stream#map` and `Stream#collect` like below:

```
  data = items.stream()
                .map(e -> new Channel_Show_Model(e.getTitle(),e.getMessage(),e.getStatus())) // map the Stream<Item> to Stream<Channel_Show_Model>
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect the result in a list
```